# how to replace [10] to {ref10} in java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

Let say if input has any number `within[ ]` which is dynamic

For example string `"the consequent hyperglycemia. [10]"`  that should be change to `"the consequent hyperglycemia. {ref10}"`

if there will be multiple citations come, for example

String  `"with diabetes. [254, 255]"` that will required to change like with diabetes. "`{ref254}{ref255}`"

Comment: Just to be clear, there would never be multiple citations (which is what I presume the `[10]` is), such that one would see `[10,11]`? Or a single sentence with multiple references?

Comment: `str.replace("[", "{ref").replace("]", "}")`?

Comment: @KevinO Yes there will be some scenario where ,  there would be multiple citations come for example 

String  “ with diabetes. [254, 255] “ required to change like  “with diabetes. {ref254}{ref255}”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
"the consequent hyperglycemia. [10]".replace("[10]", "{ref10}")
```

**Edit**

In this case you can use this regex `\[(.*?)\]` which replace every thing between `[]` for example :

```
String str = "the consequent hyperglycemia. [10]";
String result = str.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "{ref$1}");
```

**Outputs**

```
the consequent hyperglycemia. [10]    -> the consequent hyperglycemia. [ref10]
the consequent hyperglycemia. [99910] -> the consequent hyperglycemia. {ref99910}
```

---

**Edit 2**

In this case you have to use Patterns for example :

```
String str = "the consequent hyperglycemia. [10,11][12,13]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    str = str.replace(m.group(), m.group().replaceAll("(\\d+)", "{ref$1}")
            .replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\s,]", ""));
}

System.out.println(str);
```

**Outputs**

```
the consequent hyperglycemia. {ref10}{ref11}{ref12}{ref13}
```

The idea is :

1. find all the groupes between `[]`
2. replace all the ints of each grope but by `{refInt}` paralleled with replace all the `, and [ and ]`, and the result replace it with the group it self.

Comment: values in [] will be dynamic

Comment: @AndyThomas, true that the OP put that in the description, but the question title is misleading.

Comment: what about now @KevinO ?

Comment: Is the output example for `[10]` correct? It should replace to `{ref10}`, non?

Comment: @YCF_L  Thanks for the response one more help if String have "unaffected population. [10,11]" this kind of pattern then is should be change to this  "unaffected population.{ref10}{ref11}"

Comment: it was a typo @KevinO :)

Comment: @pankajdesai this information should be in the question from beginning, so can you have strings between `[...]` or just numbers separated by comma?

Comment: @YCF_L, Agree the question was poorly constructed. Assuming this question is from an academic citation, generally the available approaches are: `[10]`, `[10,11]` (the journal stipulates whether a space should be after the comma, usually no), `[10-12]` (not sure what should happen in this case, question is so far silent), `[10-12,14]`, `[10-12,14,18-26]`

Comment: yes i agree with you, this is correct @KevinO the OP should provide this in the question

Comment: @YCF_L  Apologies,  it is only number separated by comma  like this [10,11]